# how to use a subclass specific method in a different class?

Tags: java, subclass

I have 2 classes ( PhoneCall ,SMS ) that extend another ( Communication ). In a different class (Registry) I have an ArrayList that hosts all incoming communications both phone calls and sms. My assignment asks me to create a method that returns the phone call with the longest duration (attribute of class PhoneCall). So when I run through the ArrayList with the communications I get an error that says cannot resolve method getCallDuration() that exists in the PhoneCall class.

```
public PhoneCall getLongestPhoneCallBetween(String number1, String number2){
    double longestConvo=0;
    for(Communication i : communicationsRecord){
        if(i.getCommunicationInitiator()==number1 && i.getCommunicationReceiver()==number2){
            if(i.getCallDuration()>longestConvo){
            }


        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

So the program does not find the method in the Communication Class, but it is in one of its sub-Classes. 
I do not really know how to proceed. If anyone could help me out , it would be really nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the inner check to:

```
if (i instanceof PhoneCall) {
    PhoneCall phoneCall = (PhoneCall) i;
    if (phoneCall.getCallDuration() > longestConvo) {
         // Do what you need to do..
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your modified source should be like:

```
public PhoneCall getLongestPhoneCallBetween(String number1, String number2){
    double longestConvo=0;
    PhoneCall temp=null;
    for(Communication i : communicationsRecord){
        if(i instance of PhoneCall){
            PhoneCall p=(PhoneCall)i;
            if(p.getCommunicationInitiator().equals(number1) && p.getCommunicationReceiver().equals(number2)){
                if(p.getCallDuration()>longestConvo){
                    longestConvo=p.getCallDuration();
                    temp=p;   
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Where, it is checked that the instance is of `PhoneCall` class only and the `Communication` object is then casted to `PhoneCall` to get the methods specific to `PhoneCall` class. Also, you must use `.equals(Object)` to compare `String` classes.